# MS Access XLST Requirement

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-access-2010

I've reviewed several different queries on this, and I just cannot get the transform to work, I have an inkling that it's due to a lack of unique ID to identically named subheadings, but i'm not sure (not an actual dev).

The XML that I have is:

```
<MT_REQ_EXCEPTIONS>
<Header>
 <UserID>userid</UserID>
 <Password>password</Password>
 <Carrier>0000</Carrier>
 <Poster>00000000</Poster>
 <PostingDate>09092015</PostingDate>
 <OrderNumber>20150909</OrderNumber>
 <IntermediaryAccount/>
 <TransactionID>e592e236756a474daea7b9e0bbad369b</TransactionID>
 <SalesOrder>A00000000</SalesOrder>
 </Header>
<Detail>
 <IDType>40941700008493</IDType>
 <CodeType>404</CodeType>
 <CodeType2>DS3</CodeType2>
 <Field4>N</Field4>
 <Format/>
 <Discount/>
 <DifferentType/>
<Weights>
 <CodeType3>NAT</CodeType3>
 <NumberField>536</NumberField>
 <NumberField2>0</NumberField2>
 </Weights>
<Tracking>
 <ItemID/>
 </Tracking>
<CustomerData>
 <AccountID>V360284 </AccountID>
 <CustomerField1/>
 <CustomerField2/>
 <CustomerField3/>
 <CustomerField4/>
 <Numerical1/>
 <Numerical2/>
 </CustomerData>
 </Detail>
<Detail>
 <IDType>40941700008532</IDType>
 <CodeType>393</CodeType>
 <CodeType2>DS3</CodeType2>
 <Field4>N</Field4>
 <Format/>
 <Discount/>
 <DifferentType/>
<Weights>
 <CodeType3>NAT</CodeType3>
 <NumberField>536</NumberField>
 <NumberField2>0</NumberField2>
 </Weights>
<Tracking>
 <ItemID/>
 </Tracking>
<CustomerData>
 <AccountID>V360284 </AccountID>
 <CustomerField1/>
 <CustomerField2/>
 <CustomerField3/>
 <CustomerField4/>
 <Numerical1/>
 <Numerical2/>
 </CustomerData>
 </Detail>
<Trailer>
 <RecordCount>2</RecordCount>
 </Trailer>
 </MT_REQ_EXCEPTIONS>
```

What I need it to look like is:

```
<MT_REQ_EXCEPTIONS>
<Header>
 <UserID>userid</UserID>
 <Password>password</Password>
 <Carrier>0000</Carrier>
 <Poster>00000000</Poster>
 <PostingDate>09092015</PostingDate>
 <OrderNumber>20150909</OrderNumber>
 <IntermediaryAccount/>
 <TransactionID>e592e236756a474daea7b9e0bbad369b</TransactionID>
 <SalesOrder>A00000000</SalesOrder>
 </Header>
<Detail>
 <PostingDate>09092015</PostingDate>
 <IDType>40941700008493</IDType>
 <CodeType>404</CodeType>
 <CodeType2>DS3</CodeType2>
 <Field4>N</Field4>
 <Format/>
 <Discount/>
 <DifferentType/>
<Weights>
 <IDType>40941700008493</IDType>
 <CodeType3>NAT</CodeType3>
 <NumberField>536</NumberField>
 <NumberField2>0</NumberField2>
 </Weights>
<Tracking>
 <ItemID/>
 </Tracking>
<CustomerData>
 <IDType>40941700008493</IDType>
 <AccountID>V360284 </AccountID>
 <CustomerField1/>
 <CustomerField2/>
 <CustomerField3/>
 <CustomerField4/>
 <Numerical1/>
 <Numerical2/>
 </CustomerData>
 </Detail>
<Detail>
 <PostingDate>09092015</PostingDate>
 <IDType>40941700008532</IDType>
 <CodeType>393</CodeType>
 <CodeType2>DS3</CodeType2>
 <Field4>N</Field4>
 <Format/>
 <Discount/>
 <DifferentType/>
<Weights>
 <IDType>40941700008532</IDType>
 <CodeType3>NAT</CodeType3>
 <NumberField>536</NumberField>
 <NumberField2>0</NumberField2>
 </Weights>
<Tracking>
 <ItemID/>
 </Tracking>
<CustomerData>
 <IDType>40941700008532</IDType>
 <AccountID>V360284 </AccountID>
 <CustomerField1/>
 <CustomerField2/>
 <CustomerField3/>
 <CustomerField4/>
 <Numerical1/>
 <Numerical2/>
 </CustomerData>
 </Detail>
<Trailer>
 <RecordCount>2</RecordCount>
 </Trailer>
 </MT_REQ_EXCEPTIONS>
```

So far, i've been struggling just to get the PostingDate available in the Detail field, using an XLST of the following nature:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Header|Detail">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::MT_REQ_EXCEPTIONS/Header/PostingDate"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If there's any ideas on how to resolve this, it would be great. I have a feeling that the fact I can't get the PostingDate into the detail is due to the fact that the Detail doesn't have any index or uniqueness against it, and the same problem would occur with getting the IDType into the Weights, as Weights if also a field that can appear multiple times.
I'm ideally aiming to do this within Access itself, but i've attempted using XML Notepad to validate my data, to no success at all.

Hope i've explained the issue sufficiently well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, the folowing stylesheet produces the expected output:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Detail">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../Header/PostingDate"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Weights | CustomerData">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../IDType"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That's fantastic, does exactly what I want! Thanks very much.
I've attempted to add the PostingDate to the Weights and CustomerData as well, following the same structure stated here, but it doesn't seem to want to play ball. I would've thought simply adding:

<xsl:copy-of select="../Header/PostingDate"/> 

Just underneath


<xsl:copy-of select="../IDType"/>

Would have done it, but it seems not?

Comment: that's fantastic, works a charm. Thanks very much for all your help.